# Building MAUI app with native library fails under macOS

Tags: xcode, .net-core, clang, maui

I've created a MAUI application that has a referenced to a MAUI binding project with a native library but when I'm building the solution it fails with the following error:

```
0>Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1559,3): Error  : clang++ exited with code 1:
ld: in /Volumes/Eyal-X1T/Development/Projects/WowSync/src/CatalystShellBindings/bin/Debug/net8.0-maccatalyst/CatalystShellBindings.resources/libCatalystShellExtension.a(TitleBarExtension.o), building for Mac Catalyst, but linking in object file built for macOS, file '/Volumes/Eyal-X1T/Development/Projects/WowSync/src/CatalystShellBindings/bin/Debug/net8.0-maccatalyst/CatalystShellBindings.resources/libCatalystShellExtension.a' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
0>------- Finished building project: WowSync. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0
```

**Some details about my setup:**

- MacBook Air with Apple M1 chip (arm64)
- macOS Ventura 13.5.1
- .NET 8, SDK 8.0.100
- JetBrains Rider 2023.3.3
- Xcode 15.2

**This is the xcode project file `CatalystShellExtension.xcodeproj` of the native library:**

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
    archiveVersion = 1;
    classes = {
    };
    objectVersion = 56;
    objects = {

/* Begin PBXBuildFile section */
        82F8CC1E2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.m in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 82F8CC1C2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.m */; };
        82F8CC1F2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.h in Headers */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 82F8CC1D2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.h */; };
/* End PBXBuildFile section */

/* Begin PBXFileReference section */
        82F8CC102B6CD29300296FF1 /* libCatalystShellExtension.a */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; explicitFileType = archive.ar; includeInIndex = 0; path = libCatalystShellExtension.a; sourceTree = BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR; };
        82F8CC1C2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.m */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.objc; path = TitleBarExtension.m; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
        82F8CC1D2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.h */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; fileEncoding = 4; lastKnownFileType = sourcecode.c.h; path = TitleBarExtension.h; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
/* End PBXFileReference section */

/* Begin PBXFrameworksBuildPhase section */
        82F8CC0E2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Frameworks */ = {
            isa = PBXFrameworksBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
        };
/* End PBXFrameworksBuildPhase section */

/* Begin PBXGroup section */
        82F8CC072B6CD29300296FF1 = {
            isa = PBXGroup;
            children = (
                82F8CC122B6CD29300296FF1 /* CatalystShellExtension */,
                82F8CC112B6CD29300296FF1 /* Products */,
            );
            sourceTree = "<group>";
        };
        82F8CC112B6CD29300296FF1 /* Products */ = {
            isa = PBXGroup;
            children = (
                82F8CC102B6CD29300296FF1 /* libCatalystShellExtension.a */,
            );
            name = Products;
            sourceTree = "<group>";
        };
        82F8CC122B6CD29300296FF1 /* CatalystShellExtension */ = {
            isa = PBXGroup;
            children = (
                82F8CC1D2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.h */,
                82F8CC1C2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.m */,
            );
            path = CatalystShellExtension;
            sourceTree = "<group>";
        };
/* End PBXGroup section */

/* Begin PBXHeadersBuildPhase section */
        82F8CC0C2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Headers */ = {
            isa = PBXHeadersBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
                82F8CC1F2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.h in Headers */,
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
        };
/* End PBXHeadersBuildPhase section */

/* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */
        82F8CC0F2B6CD29300296FF1 /* CatalystShellExtension */ = {
            isa = PBXNativeTarget;
            buildConfigurationList = 82F8CC192B6CD29300296FF1 /* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "CatalystShellExtension" */;
            buildPhases = (
                82F8CC0C2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Headers */,
                82F8CC0D2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Sources */,
                82F8CC0E2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Frameworks */,
            );
            buildRules = (
            );
            dependencies = (
            );
            name = CatalystShellExtension;
            productName = CatalystShellExtension;
            productReference = 82F8CC102B6CD29300296FF1 /* libCatalystShellExtension.a */;
            productType = "com.apple.product-type.library.static";
        };
/* End PBXNativeTarget section */

/* Begin PBXProject section */
        82F8CC082B6CD29300296FF1 /* Project object */ = {
            isa = PBXProject;
            attributes = {
                BuildIndependentTargetsInParallel = 1;
                LastUpgradeCheck = 1520;
                TargetAttributes = {
                    82F8CC0F2B6CD29300296FF1 = {
                        CreatedOnToolsVersion = 15.2;
                    };
                };
            };
            buildConfigurationList = 82F8CC0B2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Build configuration list for PBXProject "CatalystShellExtension" */;
            compatibilityVersion = "Xcode 14.0";
            developmentRegion = en;
            hasScannedForEncodings = 0;
            knownRegions = (
                en,
                Base,
            );
            mainGroup = 82F8CC072B6CD29300296FF1;
            productRefGroup = 82F8CC112B6CD29300296FF1 /* Products */;
            projectDirPath = "";
            projectRoot = "";
            targets = (
                82F8CC0F2B6CD29300296FF1 /* CatalystShellExtension */,
            );
        };
/* End PBXProject section */

/* Begin PBXSourcesBuildPhase section */
        82F8CC0D2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Sources */ = {
            isa = PBXSourcesBuildPhase;
            buildActionMask = 2147483647;
            files = (
                82F8CC1E2B6CD2DE00296FF1 /* TitleBarExtension.m in Sources */,
            );
            runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
        };
/* End PBXSourcesBuildPhase section */

/* Begin XCBuildConfiguration section */
        82F8CC172B6CD29300296FF1 /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
                ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO;
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_GENERATE_SWIFT_ASSET_SYMBOL_EXTENSIONS = YES;
                CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL = YES;
                CLANG_ANALYZER_NUMBER_OBJECT_CONVERSION = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
                CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = "gnu++20";
                CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES;
                CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = YES;
                CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_COMMA = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE = YES_ERROR;
                CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS = YES_ERROR;
                CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
                CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE = YES;
                CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH = YES;
                COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO;
                DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf;
                ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND = YES;
                ENABLE_TESTABILITY = YES;
                ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = YES;
                GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu17;
                GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO;
                GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = YES;
                GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;
                GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = (
                    "DEBUG=1",
                    "$(inherited)",
                );
                GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION = YES;
                GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE = YES_ERROR;
                GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR = YES;
                GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
                GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION = YES;
                GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE = YES;
                LOCALIZATION_PREFERS_STRING_CATALOGS = YES;
                MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 13.5;
                MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO = INCLUDE_SOURCE;
                MTL_FAST_MATH = YES;
                ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES;
                SDKROOT = macosx;
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
        82F8CC182B6CD29300296FF1 /* Release */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
                ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO;
                ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_GENERATE_SWIFT_ASSET_SYMBOL_EXTENSIONS = YES;
                CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL = YES;
                CLANG_ANALYZER_NUMBER_OBJECT_CONVERSION = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
                CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = "gnu++20";
                CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES;
                CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = YES;
                CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_COMMA = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE = YES_ERROR;
                CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS = YES_ERROR;
                CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE = YES;
                CLANG_WARN_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
                CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE = YES;
                CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH = YES;
                COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO;
                DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = "dwarf-with-dsym";
                ENABLE_NS_ASSERTIONS = NO;
                ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND = YES;
                ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = YES;
                GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD = gnu17;
                GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS = YES;
                GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION = YES;
                GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE = YES_ERROR;
                GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR = YES;
                GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS = YES_AGGRESSIVE;
                GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION = YES;
                GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE = YES;
                LOCALIZATION_PREFERS_STRING_CATALOGS = YES;
                MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 13.5;
                MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO = NO;
                MTL_FAST_MATH = YES;
                SDKROOT = macosx;
            };
            name = Release;
        };
        82F8CC1A2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Debug */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
                CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;
                EXECUTABLE_PREFIX = lib;
                MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 14.2;
                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                SDKROOT = macosx14.2;
                SKIP_INSTALL = YES;
            };
            name = Debug;
        };
        82F8CC1B2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Release */ = {
            isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
            buildSettings = {
                CODE_SIGN_STYLE = Automatic;
                EXECUTABLE_PREFIX = lib;
                MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 14.2;
                PRODUCT_NAME = "$(TARGET_NAME)";
                SDKROOT = macosx14.2;
                SKIP_INSTALL = YES;
            };
            name = Release;
        };
/* End XCBuildConfiguration section */

/* Begin XCConfigurationList section */
        82F8CC0B2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Build configuration list for PBXProject "CatalystShellExtension" */ = {
            isa = XCConfigurationList;
            buildConfigurations = (
                82F8CC172B6CD29300296FF1 /* Debug */,
                82F8CC182B6CD29300296FF1 /* Release */,
            );
            defaultConfigurationIsVisible = 0;
            defaultConfigurationName = Release;
        };
        82F8CC192B6CD29300296FF1 /* Build configuration list for PBXNativeTarget "CatalystShellExtension" */ = {
            isa = XCConfigurationList;
            buildConfigurations = (
                82F8CC1A2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Debug */,
                82F8CC1B2B6CD29300296FF1 /* Release */,
            );
            defaultConfigurationIsVisible = 0;
            defaultConfigurationName = Release;
        };
/* End XCConfigurationList section */
    };
    rootObject = 82F8CC082B6CD29300296FF1 /* Project object */;
}
```

**This is the C# project file `CatalystShellBindings.csproj` of the bindings library:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>true</ImplicitUsings>
        <IsBindingProject>true</IsBindingProject>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ObjcBindingApiDefinition Include="ApiDefinition.cs"/>
        <ObjcBindingCoreSource Include="StructsAndEnums.cs"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <NativeReference Include="$(SolutionDir)../libs/libCatalystShellExtension.a">
            <Kind>Static</Kind>
            <ForceLoad>True</ForceLoad>
            <SmartLink>False</SmartLink>
        </NativeReference>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**This is the MAUI project file `WowSync.csproj` of the application:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFramework>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->

        <!-- Note for MacCatalyst:
        The default runtime is maccatalyst-x64, except in Release config, in which case the default is maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64.
        When specifying both architectures, use the plural <RuntimeIdentifiers> instead of the singular <RuntimeIdentifier>.
        The Mac App Store will NOT accept apps with ONLY maccatalyst-arm64 indicated;
        either BOTH runtimes must be indicated or ONLY macatalyst-x64. -->
        <!-- For example: <RuntimeIdentifiers>maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> -->

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>WowSync</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>WowSync</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.eyalalon.WowSync</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
        
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">14.2</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4"/>

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128"/>

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*"/>
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185"/>

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*"/>

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="7.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="Views\MainPage.xaml">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="Views\MainPage.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>MainPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
        <SubType>Code</SubType>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\CatalystShellBindings\CatalystShellBindings.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The xcode project and the bindings project build just fine on their own but when I reference the bindings library to the MAUI application (without calling anything at all) when building either through Rider or the CLI it fails with the error above.

I've been searching but many if not all of the results are about MAUI and iOS/Android/Windows or Xamarin but they are outdated, unfortunately, I couldn't find a complete example that show how to create a native library on xcode **with the correct settings** that targets macOS (arm64) Catalyst, a binding library for MAUI on .NET 8 and an application that consumes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to solve this you actually have to set the base SDK in Xcode to iOS as opposed to macOS then from the Xcode's Toolbar you can select Mac Catalyst but then my project wouldn't compile now because Mac Catalyst uses [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit) as opposed to  [AppKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit) but that's another issue.